# C# - Add MIP specific headers to MailMessage

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection

I have been trying to apply a sensitivity label and send an email using MIP and MailMessage.

Based on the [MipSdk-DotNet-Policy-Quickstart project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mipsdk-dotnet-policy-quickstart), I
added the option metadata `Enabled: True` and `SiteId: xxxx..` and set the content Format to `Microsoft.InformationProtection.Policy.ContentFormat.Email`.

After the action was computed i got the metadata with the mips_label key and the template id. Adding the mips_label to the MailMessage using `message.Headers.Add("msip_labels", "xxx")` adds them to the email, but when is received the label is not applied.

The label can be added via the outlook client. Is something wrong with my approach? Also, this method could be used to add cryptography using the MIP SDK?

Here some code snippets to get the action data:

```
    ExecutionStateOptions options = new ExecutionStateOptions();
    options.newLabel = action.GetLabelById(label.Id);
    options.actionSource = ActionSource.Automatic;
    options.assignmentMethod = AssignmentMethod.Privileged;
    options.contentFormat = Microsoft.InformationProtection.Policy.ContentFormat.Email;
    //options.contentIdentifier = "MyTestFile.pptx";
    options.dataState = DataState.Use;
    options.isDowngradeJustified = false;
    options.generateAuditEvent = true;
    options.metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    options.metadata.Add("Enabled", "True");
    options.metadata.Add("SiteId", "xxxxxxx");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to set Email with MIP label.
Set the property to MailItem.


to read the label:

```
var mipLabels = currentMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels/0x0000001F") as string;
```

Try this method:

```
    public void SetMIP_LabelPublic(MailItem newMailItem)
    {
        var lblID        = "00012345-0000-0000-C000-0000000000XX";    // <== change to your label ID
        var tenantId     = "00012345-0000-0000-C000-0000000XXXXX";    // <== change to your azur information tenant (your company) id
        var mipMethod    = "Privileged";            
        var dd           = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"));

        var mipPropertyText = $"MSIP_Label_{lblID}_Enabled=true; "
            + $"MSIP_Label_{lblID}_SetDate={dd}; "
            + $"MSIP_Label_{lblID}_Method={mipMethod}; "                
            + $"MSIP_Label_{lblID}_SiteId={tenantId}; ";


        newMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels/0x0000001F", mipPropertyText);
    }
```