# How to set security level in outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, microsoft-information-protection

Hi I am developing a functionality that sends emails to outlook accounts under company domain. I am using javax.mail:

```
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setRecipients("to", InternetAddress.parse(to));
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setContent(content);
        Transport.send(msg);
```

I want my messages to be titled in Outlook like this:
[image]

Is it possible to do? Is it possible to indicate C4 level of security somehow from java code?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution, we are also stuck here ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are interested in setting up MIP sensitivity label on the email. See [C# - Add MIP specific headers to MailMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71036764/c-sharp-add-mip-specific-headers-to-mailmessage) for more information.

I'd recommend exploring the Outlook internals with labels set using [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or OutlookSpy, so you could find what exactly should be set up for the message on the sender side.

Comment: Hi, please pay attention to tags, I did not mention C#, actually I think C# is the worst programming language in the world, it is slow and good for nothing :)

Comment: Ha-ha... Well, the syntax looks like C#, that is why I mentioned it in my response. I'd suggest exploring message internals (especially headers) to understand what is expected from your Java code.